# Tracking Clicks using jQuery and Ajax. I dont have access to any html/other files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I have a list of thumbnails of recipe names and i want to track which recipes people are clicking on. I problem is that i can strictly do this using jQuery and nothing else. I dont have access to any other pages of the website.

What i did so far is i checked on the  names of recipe and images and added a common class using .addClass() in jquery and just after that i declared an onclick function on that name.

Then i a taking the tile of the  tag(Which is the recipe name) and sending this information of my other website where it stores this info in database.

The problem is my clicks are not getting all of the time. The behavior looks random to me till now and i don't know how some of the clicks are getting stored and how some are not!! I researched on net and only related thing i found was to keep cache to false. I also tried that but the behavior remained the same. Clicks got stored sometime only.

I am doing this on local host right now and i need to store this info on other website of mine.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('.del-space .thumbnail a').addClass("recipeLinks");
    $(".recipeLinks" ).on("click",function(event) {
    var user=jQuery('loggedinuser').attr('title');
    //alert(user);
    if(typeof(user)==="undefined"){
        user='Guest';
    }
    var recipeName=$(this).attr('title');
    var data='recipeName='+recipeName+'&user='+user; 
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://myotherwebsite.com/tracking/storeClick.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            //alert('done');
            //window.location = location.href;
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert("error");
        }
    });  
});
```

Apart from this i am also wondering, that when i will put this code on live, where there would be a hell lot of clicks at a time, will i be able to log all the clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the click from changing the page right away so that your ajax request has time to complete, and use `window.location` to change the page once ajax is complete

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('.del-space .thumbnail a').addClass("recipeLinks");
    $(".recipeLinks" ).on("click",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //stop the default action
                            //the action will take place after
                            //ajax is complete
    var href = jQuery(this).attr("href"); //get the location to goto

    var user=jQuery('loggedinuser').attr('title');
    //alert(user);
    if(typeof(user)==="undefined"){
        user='Guest';
    }
    var recipeName=$(this).attr('title');
    var data='recipeName='+recipeName+'&user='+user; 
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://myotherwebsite.com/tracking/storeClick.php",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            //alert('done');
            window.location = href; //now goto the links href
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert("error");
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: That did solve the problem. Thanks for the solution. Now i am able to track clicks but i had to put the `window.location=href;` in the error function. **Everytime the response is going in error function**. Can you please tell why is that? Anything that i should return from my trackClick file?
And One more thing i mentioned in the question i am concerned about. Will i be able to store clicks on a live website under **heavy load** without impacting the performance much?   Thanks

Comment: alert the `textStatus` in the error function and it should tell you the reason the call is failing, as for performance as long as your click storing script can handle heavy loads and can return quickly enough than it should be fine but you will have to test

Comment: even the `textStatus` alerts error and the `errorThrown` shoes nothing on alert. Any idea? I see some javascript error  in the console, when the error pops up `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myotherwebsite.com/tracking/storeClick.php. Origin http://localhost:9001 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Any Idea?

And regarding performance, rather than manual testing, is their any way i could see how much request that click storing script can take at the time?

Comment: you need to use CORS to allow cross domain ajax requests, google "php cors" and you will find serveral things on how to enable it, for a very simple visit http://enable-cors.org/server.html, but use that simple one for testing only as it allows any domain to send a request, usually you put in a list of domains that are allowed instead of `*`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just this last thing. Any automated way i could perform performance testing?